# C++ Builder XE4 - autocompletion and syntax errors highlighting

Tags: c++, ide, c++builder-xe4

I am new to C++ Builder. I am trying out the XE4 version, but it doesn't seem to have autocompletion for include or checking and underlining a bad syntax like for example VS does. So I can put any rubbish and the editor doesn't indicate in any way that you made a mistake in your code. And as for auto completing include: when including headers it doesn't indicate anything if the headers exists. Does any one knows if these 2 features should work in C++ Builder XE4 and you just need to switch them on somewhere or they don't exist in this IDE ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used C++ Builder XE4 ...  but on earlier versions, you could go into `Tools > Options > Editor Options > Code Insight`.

Q: Does that option exist in XE4?  Does it help?

ALSO: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Code_Completion

Comment: Yes, I have switched on autocompletion there but still it doesn't auto complete for includes, and it doesn't underline errors in editor.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problems for years now. It's only my personal opinion, but I think this kind of things are broken in C++Builder. The main IDE / programming language is Delphi / Object Pascal. They work and write primary with this one and make all kind of wrappers, etc. for C++ afterwards. In Delphi everything works normally. In C++ autocomplation DOES work, but seldom. Sometimes it pops up and sometimes not. I never managed to get syntax checking to work in realtime. Only after compilation the checking starts... sometimes. There are other things which don't work too, like the Refactoring feature which I use (in Delphi) to find and add missing libraries/headers to the "uses" list. This worked partly in previous C++Builder XE versions but doesn't work at all now. Also, all this features seems to be much slower in C++Builder.

That's sad. I liked the solid functionality in Borland's products, like in C++Builder 6. The documentation system (help) worked there wonderfully too. In Delphi / C++Builder it is slow and incomplete, because it is made with one of the worst documentation systems at all: Microsoft Document Explorer. :-(

Comment: in 2018 with the C++ Builder 10.2.3 Tokyo ... I still agree with this answer.